# Creating a responsive table for displaying data from database

Tags: html, mysql

I need to create a form containing only a text box and a submit button.
I need to store datas in the database. The data that are stored in the database is employee's address, I need to store the old and new address for the employees. So the database should contain multiple columns for a row, assuming that each column contains the address of the employee. Some employees may have 1 address and some employees may have multiple address.

Now, with the created form. When I typed the Employee ID in the text box and searched. It should display the all the address from the database for the given ID. Important:It should not display the columns that are left blank.

While displaying the data, it should contain a edit button near to the data field so that the data can be manipulated.

I am using mySQL. How I should achieve displaying only the data but not the empty fields.

Comment: have you tried anything??

Comment: A simple `WHERE address IS NOT NULL AND address <> ''` would suffice. But you should consider providing more code here as I have no idea how to answer this properly.